# Display Custom Post Type Post Title in Column, by Referencing Post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a (potentially) complicated question related to WordPress custom post types, and how to display custom meta from those types in columns in the admin section of the site. I have two custom post types on my site: "Leagues" and "Teams." Each team has a custom user meta that connects it to a league. The meta for that team is set as 'team_league', and has a numeric value that equals the post ID of the corresponding league CPT.

I added some code to make the "League" meta appear in a column under the "Teams" custom post type. However, I'd like to take it a step farther, as it only displays the Post ID for the corresponding league. Is it possible to display the post title in the column, referenced by looking up the post ID and printing the post title.

Example: post ID 98215 = post title "Spring - Women's League - Th".

Here is my code for adding custom meta to the CPT columns:

```
// Add the custom columns to the Teams post type:

add_filter( 'manage_team_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_team_columns' );
function set_custom_edit_team_columns($columns) {
  $columns['sport_name'] = __( 'Sport', 'your_text_domain' );
  $columns['team_league'] = __( 'League', 'your_text_domain' );
  $columns['current_paid_amount'] = __( 'Amount Paid', 'your_text_domain' );

  return $columns;
 }

 // Add the data to the custom columns for the Teams post type:

 add_action( 'manage_team_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_team_column', 10, 2 );
 function custom_team_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {

    case 'sport_name' :
        echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'sport_name' , true ); 
        break;

    case 'team_league' :
        echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'team_league' , true ); 
        break;

    case 'current_paid_amount' :
        echo '$' . get_post_meta( $post_id , 'current_paid_amount' , true ); 
        break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution for my own problem after trying some things. I used the following code below, in place of what I posted above to print the meta to the column:

```
case 'team_league' :
        echo get_post(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'team_league', true))->post_title; 
        break;
```

This produces the result I was looking for, printing the post title rather than the post ID.